# POI 3.5 WorkBook Exception for XML creation?

Tags: xml, exception, apache-poi

I  have downloaded latest POI 3.5 and tried to run sample application for creation of excel sheet.But it is always giving error while exceuting some code like:

```
enter code here
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); //or new HSSFWorkbook();
```

Generated Exception all the time is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at ExcelSheetCreation.main(ExcelSheetCreation.java:38)

please give solution for the given exception,
why is it giving such kind of exception,as i have included all the types of POI 3.5 jars.?
What to include more in the project?

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Maven, include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

In particular, the problem is beacause you don't have the Apache xmlbeans dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```